# Performance issue with $first in my query

Tags: mongodb

I have intermediate level experience in Mongo DB. Recently we started a project on Analytics where I have a collection with 1 million documents. When I run below query, it is taking more than 30 seconds to get the results. If I remove **$first**, same query is not taking more than 3 sec.

How to improve the performance?

```
db.ETLCollection.aggregate(
[
{
  "$sort":{"CreatedDate":-1}
},
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {"FromOrgId":"$FromOrgId","ProductId":"$ProductId"},
        document: { "$first": "$$CURRENT" }
        }
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
       "TotalInventory": {
                "$sum": "$document.inventory"
            }
    }
    }


],{allowDiskUse:true});
```

Comment: You can try to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/ to understand what is the difference between the queries in execution. and for profiler https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-query-performance/

Comment: It didn't help me, Please provide a constructive solution.